# Background snapshot task watchOS

Tags: swiftui, watchos

Since in real device im receiving the snapshot task as the app goes to background.
Later after 1hr I receive a another snapshot task and that's it, I don't receive further any task.
Is there anything needs to be added, I want regular working of snapshot task every 1hr.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp_Watch_AppApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .backgroundTask(.appRefresh) { context in
        // Handle tasks with the "MY_FIRST_IDENTIFIER" identifier.
            print("App Refresh Task with 'MY_FIRST_IDENTIFIER' has been triggered.")
        // Add any additional logic you want to execute during the task.
        
        // Schedule the background refresh task with a 15-minute delay.
            await WKApplication.shared()
            .scheduleBackgroundRefresh(
                withPreferredDate: Date.init(timeIntervalSinceNow:60.0),
                userInfo: nil) { error in
                    if error != nil {
                        // Handle the scheduling error.
       fatalError("*** An error occurred while scheduling the background   refresh task. ***")
                    }
                    
                    
                    print("*** Scheduled! ***")
                }
    }
    
        .backgroundTask(.snapshot) { snapshotData in
        // Update your UI for the snapshot.
        
        print("SNAPSHOT")
        await WKApplication.shared()
            .scheduleBackgroundRefresh(
                withPreferredDate: Date.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60.0),
                userInfo:nil) { error in
                    if error != nil {
                        // Handle the scheduling error.
     fatalError("*** An error occurred while scheduling the background refresh task. ***")
                    }
                    
                    
                    print("*** Scheduled! ***")
                }
        return SnapshotResponse(estimatedSnapshotExpiration: .distantFuture)
    }
}
```

}